# The symbol for a map which is an isomorphism?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Suppose I have a map *A* → *B* which is an isomorphism. I'd like to represent this as something that looks like `\rightarrow` with `\sim`under it. I could try `\underset{}_{}`, but is there already a ready made symbol?

I couldn't find the symbol using Detexify, nor in the comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols.

Comment: You want the `\sim` _under_ the `\to`? Odd. I don't think I've ever seen an isomorphism written like that.

Answer (score 11):

Theoretically, you could use `\xrightarrow[\sim]{}` (from `amsmath`) or `\xlongrightarrow[\sim]{}` (from `extarrows`). Both look horrible though. The `\sim` on top of the arrow (like `\xlongrightarrow{\sim}`) looks somewhat better.

Unicode defines ⥴ (U+2974 RIGHTWARDS ARROW ABOVE TILDE OPERATOR), which you can use in case you run Xe/LuaLaTeX with `unicode-math` (either directly or with the `\rightarrowsimilar` alias). There are also ⥱ (`\equalrightarrow`), ⥲ (`\similarrightarrow`), ⥳ (`\leftarrowsimilar`), ⥵ (`\rightarrowapprox`) and other strange things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! For me `\xrightarrow{\sim}`  is quite enough.

Answer (score 9):

A bit of adjustment of the spacing may help. For example, with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fixltx2e}
\newcommand*\MapsTo{%
  \xrightarrow[\raisebox{0.25 em}{\smash{\ensuremath{\sim}}}]{}%
}
\begin{document}
Test \( x \MapsTo y \) test.
\end{document}
```

I feel the result is not tool bad. You may need to adjust the amount of vertical shift to suite the font in use. I've not scaled-down the `\sim` here, as it's not clear from the original question if it should be full-sized or small. It would be easy enough to do that, though, if necessary.

Comment: (+1) How to adjust space when we want the symbol *over* the arrow? I tried with `\xrightarrow{\raisebox{-0.25 em}{\smash{\ensuremath{\sim}}}}` but doens't work.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Try \xrightarrow{\raisebox{-0.7ex}[0ex][0ex]{$\sim$}} (taken from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479324/35477)