# Help with better isomorphic function symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I'm trying to us TikZcd to create a better isomorphic mapping symbol. I've seen the other posts about this issue and they're all terrible, and they even acknowledge their solutions aren't great. 
[The symbol for a map which is an isomorphism?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/the-symbol-for-a-map-which-is-an-isomorphism)

I personally think the arrow below is kind of nice (with some adjustments), where the example is the arrow from 1 to 2:
[image]

This is produced by the code

```
$1 \hspace{-0.4cm} 
\begin{tikzcd}
  \phantom{1} \arrow[r, "\sim"] & \phantom{1}
\end{tikzcd} 
\hspace{-0.4cm}
2$
```

Since, this is a bit messy, I wanted to put this into a command like so

```
\newcommand*\isomap{
\hspace{-0.4cm} 
\begin{tikzcd}
  \phantom{1} \arrow[r, "\sim"] & \phantom{1}
\end{tikzcd} 
\hspace{-0.4cm}
}
```

But I get the error

```
Package pgf: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
```

I've looked up this error but the results aren't relevant to my situation (as far as I can tell). Any ideas on how I can get this into a command?

Comment: Do you know `\xrightarrow`?

Comment: Yes, but I think it looks a bit weird. There's also ```\xlongrightarrow``` but that also looks strange to me.

Comment: Please, tell us, why do you think strange? Is the arrow too short? Or too long?

Comment: I think it's too short.

Comment: To make your command work, you can use an `ampersand replacement`: `\newcommand*\isomap{
\hspace{-0.4cm} 
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \phantom{1} \arrow[r, "\sim"] \& \phantom{1}
\end{tikzcd} 
\hspace{-0.4cm}
}` but is unnecessarily complicated IMHO. Once you load `tikz` (which `tikz-cd` does) you have much simpler options.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean simpler options?

Comment: Something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\isomap{\xrightarrow{~~\raisebox{-1pt}{$\sim$}~~}}
$1\isomap2$
\end{document}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another suggestion, with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\isomarrow}{\mathrel{\setstackgap{S}{-0.5pt}\ensurestackMath{\Shortstack{\scriptstyle\sim\\ \longrightarrow}}}}

\begin{document}

\[ 1 \isomarrow 2\]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty nice, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution without `tikz-cd`, using `\xrightarrow` with a box in predefined length (I used `1cm`).

[image]

The command contains 2 arguments to be used as domain and codomain, like `\isomap{x}{y}` for example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\newcommand{\isomap}[2]{$ #1 \xrightarrow{\makebox[1cm]{$\sim$}} #2 $}

\begin{document}
the operator $\otimes$ is invariant up to isomorphism \isomap{1}{2}.

the operator $\otimes$ is invariant up to isomorphism \isomap{x}{y}.    
\end{document}
```